# Run bash script in background by default

Tags: bash, background-process

I know I can run my bash script in the background by using `bash script.sh & disown` or alternatively, by using `nohup`. However, I want to run my script in the background by default, so when I run `bash script.sh` or after making it executable, by running `./script.sh` it should run in the background by default. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-contained solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Re-spawn as a background process, if we haven't already.
if [[ "$1" != "-n" ]]; then
    nohup "$0" -n &
    exit $?
fi

# Rest of the script follows. This is just an example.
for i in {0..10}; do
    sleep 2
    echo $i
done
```

The if statement checks if the `-n` flag has been passed. If not, it calls itself with `nohup` (to disassociate the calling terminal so closing it doesn't close the script) and `&` (to put the process in the background and return to the prompt). The parent then exits to leave the background version to run. The background version is explicitly called with the `-n` flag, so wont cause an infinite loop (which is hell to debug!).

The for loop is just an example. Use `tail -f nohup.out` to see the script's progress.

Note that I pieced this answer together with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792932/run-current-bash-script-in-background) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967251/bash-script-that-will-survive-disconnection-but-not-user-break) but neither were succinct or complete enough to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write a wrapper that calls your actual script with `nohup actualScript.sh &`.

Wrapper script wrapper.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

nohup ./actualScript.sh &
```

Actual script in actualScript.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in {0..10}
do
    sleep 10  #script is running, test with ps -eaf|grep actualScript
    echo $i 
done
```

tail -f 10 nohup.out

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

Comment: Is there away to do it from inside the script though?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620810/3697870 Sorry for the almost identical answer, but couldn't contain it to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Heath Raftery's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620810/2864686), what worked for me is a variation of what he suggested such as this:

```
if [[ "$1" != "-n" ]]; then
    $0 -n & disown
    exit $?
fi
```